# How to bring my application activity if another application is in visible?

Tags: android

Consider am having 2 applications named first and second. The first applications has activity A the second applications has activity B. Initially Activity A of first application is launched and later second application will be launched from the activity A of the first application. Activity A of the first application has a count down timer. Once the timer hits How can i bring the activity A, being the application second is in visible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need them to be different applications? Couldn't they just be activities in the same applications?

That said, you could just use an [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and start your activity that has an intent-filter for that intent?

Answer (score 0):

hi try something like below code

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.urbanairship.airmail", "com.urbanairship.airmail.MainListActivity");
                    intent.setComponent(cn);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity( intent);
```